# Building the foundations of DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have seen tons of times that $f(x)=f'(x)$ implies $f(x)=Ce^x$. But the "proof" involves a division by $f(x)$.

My question:

> Suppose that $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is a continuous, differentiable function such that $f'(x)=f(x)$. Is it true that $f(x)=ae^x$ for some $a>0$ or $f\equiv 0$?

Comment: The constant $a$ could also be negative, which means that you could say that $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: May I ask you what's wrong with the division by $f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a solution $f$, define $u(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$. Now,
$$
Du(x)=-e^{-x}f(x)+e^{-x}Df(x)=0 \quad\text{for all real $x$}.
$$
Hence $u$ is a constant function, i.e. there exists $C\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $u(x)=C$ for all real $x$. This means that $f(x)=Ce^x$ for all real $x$, and $C$ can be either zero or any real number. Notice that I did not make any division.